# Form duplication of field, before MySQL posting of data

Tags: java, php, mysql, forms, duplicate-data

I have almost managed to fix a long standing problem I've been having with duplicate fields in my website, today I got a very quick solution to make the column data unique. An easy fix that had escaped me.

However this leaves an auto increment entry to the database, with null values except for ID (primary column). You can see the effect this has in the website, LostDots.com

I have tried all the INSERT IGNORE options, and this didn't fix it either.

So I was thinking if it might be possible to use the validate form coding to eliminate entires before it gets sent to MySQL. i.e.

```
 if (theForm.Editbox2.value == "")
  {
  alert("at least put a X");
  theForm.Editbox2.focus();
  return false;
  }
  if (theForm.Editbox2.value.length < 1)
  {
  alert("at least put a X");
  theForm.Editbox2.focus();
  return false;
  }
```

As an example of what I was thinking, maybe if I pulled up the variable for the Editbox2 value, and got it to compare?

```
  if (theForm.Editbox2.value = $namevariable)
  {
  alert("That domain name has already been advertised !!");
  theForm.Editbox2.focus();
  return false;
  }
```

Having previously queried the present table data

```
  (SELECT EDITBOX2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS $namevariable);
```

I am only wondering if this could be possible, I think getting the variable into Java is the problem? Maybe I haven't slept enough and speaking jibberish.

Let me know if it might be possible. Thanks, Alastair.

Comment: Ever think of setting your column(s) as UNIQUE?

Comment: Did that, new entry to database is made as a result. Or have I missed something in this simple process. Ta

Comment: Another method to check for duplicates is `num_rows()` or if you want to select unique values from DB, use `DISTINCT`. If not that, then I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: The problem I have is that I want to avoid the default action of the auto increment input of a new record whenever, in this case, a domain name is entered twice, when it would be impossible for the name to have more than one format.

Comment: Has anyone tried to check for duplicates at the form entry stage?

Comment: Sure you can. You just query ahead of time, if a row matches, then kill the process. If it doesn't then continue with the query, whether it's an INSERT, UPDATE, other.

Comment: So I haven't gone mad staring at the screen all night. Will look into this further and see if I can work it out. Thanks for maintaining my sanity.

Comment: You're quite welcome.